# Can input function take a macro variable as character argument?

Tags: sas

SAS says: ERROR: INPUT function requires a character argument.
when I run the following code:

```
%let fyq0 = 000930 ;
%put &fyq0 ;
proc sql ;
create table check as
select *, input(&fyq0,yymmdd6.) as fyq0
from q ;
quit ;
```

I tried to have '&fyq0' instead of &fyq0 as the 1st argument for the -input- function as the following:

```
%let fyq0 = 000930 ;
%put &fyq0 ;
proc sql ;
create table check as
select *, input('&fyq0',yymmdd6.) as fyq0
from q ;
quit ;
```

Then SAS says: NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT. Missing values may be generated. And indeed, variable fyq0 returns a missing value.

I wonder what went wrong with my approaches and what is the correct way to go.

Comment: Try “&fyq0” in double quotes not single quotes. Macro vars don’t resolve inside single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The macro processor just replaces the macro reference with the resolved text and then the generated text is interpreted as text.  So when you tried.

```
input(&fyq0,yymmdd6.)
```

it was the same as if your code was

```
input(000930,yymmdd6.)
```

Even if that did run SAS would first have to convert the number 930 into a character string using the BEST12. format which would result in a string like

```
'         930'
```

and the input function would only read 6 of the leading spaces.

The macro processor does not process text inside of single quotes. So the INPUT function could not convert the five character string '&fyq0' to a valid date since the letters and ampersand are not valid digits.

You can use double quote characters to allow SAS to resolve the macro variable reference.

```
input("&fyq0",yymmdd6.)
```

Now the macro variable reference will resolve and code generated will be:

```
input("000930",yymmdd6.)
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom! Why would SAS read 000930 as a number instead of a string when I use input(&fyq0,yymmdd6.)? I thought SAS always "see" the content of macro variables as strings.

Comment: Read my answer more carefully and you will see.  If you are still confused try to understand why SAS will treat `123` as a number instead of a string.  And why does it treat `check` as the name of a dataset instead of a string or a variable name.

Comment: I can see why INPUT function would read 000930 as a number as all characters in this string are numbers. However, I would think if I define &fyq0, as 2000-09-30, then `INPUT(&fyq0, yymmdd10.) `should work because 2000-09-30 should be interpreted as a string. Alternatively, if I define &fyq0 as 
30SEP2000, then  `INPUT(&fyq0, date9.)` should work. But it turns out INPUT function just cannot work with them. I think using "&fyq0" as the 1st argument for the INPUT function is always correct in terms of grammar, but these nuances indeed confuse me.

Comment: The expression `2000-09-30` is equal to the number `1961`.  Remember that once the macro processor has finished converting the text of the program the resulting text is handle exactly as if it was typed that way to begin with.